# Is $(a+b)^2$ always greater than equal to zero, if we consider $a$ and $b$ to be complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers then will the given condition stand TRUE?
And if $a$ and $b$ are not complex numbers will the identity (a+b^2 be greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: The complex numbers are not an ordered field: there is no general notion of order between complex numbers.

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}$ you can't even compare the order of terms so there is no $\ge 0$

Comment: If you are referring to the magnitude of a complex number, then as long as $a$ and $b$ are not all equal to zero, then the magnitude of $(a + b)^2$ is greater than zero.

Comment: Beyond that, when allowing complex numbers it is possible for the square of the sum of two complex numbers to be a negative real number, for trivial example $(i+i)^2=-4$

Comment: Nope.  Obviously  $(i+i)^2 = (2i)^2 = -4 < 0$.  This is actually *exactly* why the complex numbers can not have order. (In an ordered field we have $a> 0 \implies a^2 > 0*a =0$ and if $a< 0$ then $0 < -a$ so $a^2 =(-a)^2 > -a*0 = 0$.  and $0^2 =0$.  So $a^2 \ge 0$ but $i^2   =-1$ and $1^2 =1$ so if $i^2=-1 > 0$ then $0 < 1$ but $1^2> 0$ too.... so no order is possible.)

Answer (score 1):

What about $a=1+i$ and $b=-1+i$? There $(a+b)^2$ is negative and therefore less than 0.

The **magnitude**, however, of every complex number $c+di$; $c$, $d$ real, is $c^2+d^2$ which is always nonegstive real and positive if either $c,d$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $a = i$ and $b = 0$.