# Will $3i$ be a positive number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I came across this question while reading quadratic equations ?
$3i$ which can be expressed as $\sqrt{-9}$ will be a positive or a negative number ?

Comment: Someone told you yesterday in the comments to [this qusetion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4055839/29335) that there is no sensible notion of order on the complex numbers... discussing their positivity and negativity amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering on complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492890/ordering-on-complex-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

$3i$ is a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) that is not a [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_numbers), so it's neither positive nor negative. Positive numbers have [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) $0$ and negative numbers have argument $\pi$, whereas $\operatorname{Arg}(3i)=\frac\pi2$.

Comment: @TheNerd Positivity & negativity refers only to numbers on the real line, not general complex numbers on the real-imaginary (complex) plane.